# Terminal broken.

Tags: terminal, homebrew, iterm

I am having an issue and I have no clue what I should be searching to fix it. Not experienced enough.

I have zsh and probably other things I installed many years ago while making the terminal more my style such as iterm2 and etc. Not sure how to list or find the list of them.

Recently, I utilized CleanMyMac software to delete an app. Can't remember which.

Since, I have been getting the following:
[image]

It is produced in both iterm2 and the terminal.

Not sure what to search for as it isn't an error. However, I cannot run scripts I usually do. I cannot auto complete with Tabs. Might be more of what I cannot do.

I tried:

- brew update
- brew reinstall zsh
- brew unlink zsh
- brew link zsh
- brew doctor

Any suggestions or what should be by next step in figuring out the issue.
I am guessing a starter file/script/settings must of been deleted or renamed ?

Comment: Did you try `exec bash` to see if your bash shell is working normally? Then `exec zsh` to come back. Your screenshot looks like your login config file has a problem.

Comment: Check your zsh startup files (.zshrc probably) for errors.

Comment: @Yoric it looks normal, I can move around. Tabs auto complete is working. I'll try more tomorrow during a break.

Comment: @nohillside, how to check for errors ?

Comment: Something there is creating the output you see

Comment: @nohillside, okay thank you. I will look into zsh community/documentation.

Comment: @nohillside, thanks for pointing that zsh was broken. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used brew to uninstall zsh

```
brew remove zsh
```

I installed it again.

```
brew install zsh
```

Fixed everything.